# How to install CMSIS package for Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, stm32, keil, cmsis

I want to install CMSIS pack provided by [Keil](https://github.com/ARM-software/cmsis-pack-eclipse). The page says to download the source code and install from Help Menu of Eclipse. But when I select the folder it is showing an error "Could not find file 'jar:file:/path/cmsis-pack-eclipse-master'". Somebody help me. I'm using windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

I have succeed to install CMSIS package yesterday, I am using Eclipse Oxygen now.
I also saw same message when trying with web site, instead of it, I downloaded CmsisPackPlugIn2.3.2.zip file from https://github.com/ARM-software/cmsis-pack-eclipse/releases and install via Help > Install New Software... > Add... > Archive...

Please refer here, https://github.com/ARM-software/cmsis-pack-eclipse/issues/65

Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

I installed it today by click "Make the CMSIS Packs perspective visible", then click "Update the CMSIS packs definitions".